# Directx 11: Rebuilding triangles in support of quads

Tags: c++, algorithm, directx-11, texture-mapping, .obj

A while ago I've created an obj parser to better support my Maya/Game interface. I compromised on triangulating every model in Maya, but after noticing the support in other packages, how would you rebuild your triangulated workflow from a quad obj file? IE:

```
f 1//1 4//4 3//3 2//2
```

Of course, such that texture coordinates are compatible, or synced. (Or I may have to reconfigure)Any help is appreciated. Sometimes I'll get it talking about it.

Edit: Also, a link to resources for face splitting is useful. I can't seem to wrap my mind around it.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking about, but if you mean you want to parse obj files that contain quads instead of triangles then you'll just need to create two triangles in place of a quad. You may also have your parser detect which representation is used by the file and then proceed accordingly.

Comment: Would they share two vertices? Is that for every second triangle utilize the fourth point? Currently, my parser detects for the fourth coordinate, then throws an error about the file, ie: "You are attempting to load a file with quads, please format the file as tris."

Comment: Yes, from a quad a,b,c,d you'll get two triangles: a,b,d and d,b,c.

Comment: Thanks so much, I think it's safe to assume texture coordinates will be proper in the obj too? (As they are generated.)

Comment: You could finalize that as an answer for future eyes. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to change how your application handles meshes internally (i.e. switch from passing triangles to the pipeline to passing quads) the easiest solution is to alter your parser so that it creates two triangles in place of each quad.

For each face:

```
f v1 v2 v3 v4
```

You'll want to create two triangles: `v1 v2 v4` and `v4 v2 v3`.

Per vertex data like normals and texture coordinates will stay the same.